# How to debug performance issue/optimize your meteor app

Tags: performance, meteor

I just deployed my Meteor app onto a production server on Digital Ocean.
I noticed that for about 7500 documents, it takes about 3-5 seconds to fully fetch the objects (selectively taking only 3 fields) and populate the autocomplete data. I believe it should rather be instantenous for such number of data, so I am curious how I can debug performance issues from here and optimize more. How should I go about debugging performance issues for a Meteor app? I tried seeing the network tab but nothing seems to take more than a second. I am not sure why it takes 3-5 seconds for the search bar with an autocomplete feature to get ready. After a close inspection, populating autocomplete fields is instantaneous, and the time until `subscribe` function's callback is called is about `3 to 5` seconds.

I've already looked into [Kadira](http://kadira.io), but it reported that everything was complete within milliseconds, so I am confused.

possibly related: [Meteor's subscription and sync are slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298640/meteors-subscription-and-sync-are-slow)

After all, is 3-5 seconds for 7800 documents with 2 fields reasonable?

Comment: I looked into kadira but it also reported that everything was complete within milliseconds, so I am confused.

Comment: I've added this comment into the question. It's good practice to put everything you've tried in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me tell you what's really happening here.

Kadira shows the time taken to fetch the data from the server and queue it to the network. So, 500 - 700 ms is reasonable for that.

So, this 3-5 ms latency is the network latency. That means the time taken to send data to the client via the network. It's quite okay for 7500+ documents even with three fields over DDP.

So, my suggestion is to do the search on the server and use something like [Search Source](https://github.com/meteorhacks/search-source) for that.

With that, you'll get the only data required to the client. Which reduce the latency and saves the CPU of your app.